# event get not executed

Tags: mysql-5.7, event

I'm on 2 debian8 box's with mysql-5.7.19.

I have a master slave replication running, replicating one db (db1.1) from master to slave (db2.1).
Replicated db's on master and slave have same names.

Master has another db (db1.2) that pulls some statistical data out of db1.1.
That happens by means of some views (getting data from db1.1) in db1.2 and an event in db1.2 that calls a procedure.

Now I like to take that statistical workload of from master and put it on the slave.

I created another db, db2.2 on slave with identical table and views as in db1.2. 
Names of db1.2 and db2.2 are different.

Created same procedure on slave as on master and an event with another name on slave.db2.2 that calls that procedure.

If I call the procedure by hand on slave it does what it supposed to do. Copies all data as expected.

But calling that procedure by an event on slave doesn't run.
Names of the events on master and slave are different.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After having a nap I found solution by myself.

The Event Scheduler was not running on the slave machine.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

did the trick.

It's running now.